# Apply a value to all instances of a number based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
  ID     Number   
  1        0  
  1        0
  1        1
  2        0
  2        0
  3        1
  3        1
  3        0
```

I want to apply a 5 to any ids that have a 1 anywhere in the number column and a zero to those that don't.  For example, if the number "1" appears anywhere in the Number column for ID 1, I want to place a 5 in the total column for every instance of that ID.

My desired output would look as such

```
  ID     Number    Total 
  1        0        5
  1        0        5
  1        1        5
  2        0        0
  2        0        0
  3        1        5
  3        1        5
  3        0        5
```

Trying to think of a way leverage applymap for this issue but not sure how to implement.

Comment: Why are the Total values for the first two rows 5? Ditto the last row. You say you only want a 5 when the number column is 1, but those rows have Number = 0.

Comment: Honestly, 5 was a completely arbitrary choice :)  It could be any value/letter/symbol.  The idea here is that each ID has several numbers associated with it (e.g. 0, 0, 1 for ID 1).  My goal is that if the number one appears anywhere in the Number column for ID 1 for example, I want to place a 5 in the total column for every instance of that ID.

Comment: No, you misunderstand: why is there a non-zero value in the first two rows and the last row: they don't match the criterion you give, which looks whether Number is 1 or 0.

Comment: I think Anand's answer has clarified and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `ID` column and then take [`max()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) of the `Number` column, and then make that into a dictionary and then use that to create the `'Total'` column. Example -

```
grouped = df.groupby('ID')['Number'].max().to_dict()
df['Total'] = df.apply((lambda row:5 if grouped[row['ID']] else 0), axis=1)
```

Demo -

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
   ID  Number
0   1       0
1   1       0
2   1       1
3   2       0
4   2       0
5   3       1
6   3       1
7   3       0

In [56]: grouped = df.groupby('ID')['Number'].max().to_dict()

In [58]: df['Total'] = df.apply((lambda row:5 if grouped[row['ID']] else 0), axis=1)

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   ID  Number  Total
0   1       0      5
1   1       0      5
2   1       1      5
3   2       0      0
4   2       0      0
5   3       1      5
6   3       1      5
7   3       0      5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to add a column to your df as a result of a `groupby` on 'ID':

```
In [6]:
df['Total'] = df.groupby('ID').transform(lambda x: 5 if (x == 1).any() else 0)
df

Out[6]:
   ID  Number  Total
0   1       0      5
1   1       0      5
2   1       1      5
3   2       0      0
4   2       0      0
5   3       1      5
6   3       1      5
7   3       0      5
```